# to create a population of "A" and "B" alphabets with 50% frequency of each

Tags: python, list, random

I am writing this code to generate a txt file which should have total of 600 letters comprising only of A(50%) and B(50%), distributed randomly. How should I do that, I am new to coding, please help.

```
q=[A, B]
popsize=500
def gen_pop(A):
      population=[]
      B=A
      while len(population)<popsize:
             random.shuffle(B)
             print A
         print B

gen_pop(q)
```

Comment: Do you want it to be exactly half `A` and half `B`, or do you want each letter to be chosen independently with probability of 50% (resulting in a normal distribution for the number of each)?

Answer (score 4):

Create a list of 300 `A` and 300 `B` the shuffle it with `random.shuffle`:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> mylist = ['A'] * 300 + ['B'] * 300
>>> shuffle(mylist)
>>> mylist
 ['B', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A', ... 'A', 'B', 'A']
```

Answer (score 4):

The best answer may depend on what exactly you want your distribution to be.

If you want exactly half your letters to be `A` and half to be `B`, use the technique from jabaldoneodo's answer, and build the sequence first, then shuffle it:

```
 import random

 result = ["A"]*300 + ["B"]*300
 random.shuffle(result)
```

If on the other hand, you want each value to be selected independently of the others, with a 50% chance of it being `A` and a 50% chance of it being `B`, picking the number of each ahead of time will be inappropriate. Instead, you can use `random.choice` to pick from your alphabet in a list comprehension:

```
 import random

 alphabet = "AB"
 result = [random.choice(alphabet) for _ in range(600)]
```

Using this method, the number of `A`s (and `B`s, for that matter) will be normally distributed, with a mean of 300. The same technique also works for larger alphabets.

Answer (score 2):

Generate an array of 300 A's and 300 B's, and then shuffle it using an [algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).